# Can any one tell me how to start zoom out from last zoom in point in android?

Tags: android, animation, zooming

When an app is opened then then an image should be automatically zoom in and from that point it should be zoomed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use selector ..u can solve that problem

zoom in

```
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <scale
    android:duration="10000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="3"
    android:toYScale="3" >
    </scale>
</set>
```

Zoom out

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >
<scale
android:duration="10000"
android:fromXScale="3"
android:fromYScale="3"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toXScale="1.0"
android:toYScale="1.0" >
</scale>
</set>
```